# Regex pattern for matching string inbetween two /backslashes/ that comes directly after a first match of another string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

So I have these strings:

- **"app/modules/one/file.js"**
- **"app/modules/two/dwadwa.js"**
- **"app/modules/three/ffff.js"**

and I would like to always match the next segment after the modules segment (i.e. one, two and three). Tried in vain trying to get a pattern to work but I just don't understand Regex enough to be able to do it. Writing this regex within a **JavaScript** environment.

Comment: Slash = `/` Backslash = `\\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `()` to capture the second part:

```js
var strings = [
  "app/modules/one/file.js",
  "app/modules/two/dwadwa.js",
  "app/modules/three/ffff.js"
];

strings.forEach(function(s) {
  var m = s.match(/modules\/([^\/]*)/);
  console.log(m[1]);
})
```

Comment: @user3388195 -- but do you understand it?